# Transactionscope not rollingback with firebird

Tags: c#, entity, firebird, transactionscope

I have a problem using transaction scope, it's not rolling back. Here is my code, I'm using

Entity version 6.1.3 and
Firebird ADO.NET Provider version 5.8.0

I'm using 2 databases, one for data and another for files. I need to commit in both or none

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMultiRepositorio()
{

    //UOW uow = new UOW();
    //var repoCliente = uow.IncluiOuObtemRepositorioTipado<ClientesRepositorio>();
    //var repoDocumento = uow.IncluiOuObtemRepositorioTipadoGED<DocumentosRepositorio>();

    //new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions() { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted })

    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))
    using (IContexto ctx = new ContextoInterlitis())
    using (IContexto ctxGED = new ContextoGED())
    {

        IRepository<Cliente> repoCliente = new ClientesRepositorio(ctx);
        IRepository<Documento> repoDocumento = new DocumentosRepositorio(ctxGED);

        var listaClientes = repoCliente.Buscar(c => c.Nome.Contains("Prefeitura"));
        var cliente = listaClientes.FirstOrDefault();

        cliente.Nome = "Teste";

        ctx.SaveChanges();

        var documento = new Documento() { CaminhoDocumento = @"D:\Formatador.txt" };

        //Add
        repoDocumento.Incluir(documento);

        //Rollback?
        throw new Exception("Teste!");

        ctxGED.SaveChanges();

        cliente.Nome = "Prefeitura de Teste Alterada";

        ctx.SaveChanges();

        scope.Complete();
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `Suppress` cause it to **not** use a transaction?

Comment: I try all options... but i found the problem... firebird have a little changes to do to work with transactionscope